# Preciso saber como posso matar/deletar um objeto

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x

Estou com um programa, no qual há alguns objetos, que no caso são "blobs" ou seres redondos, que por meio de **ids**(números de identificação) podem se matar, porém não consigo fazer com que a morte de fato aconteça, tentei usar na classe dos blobs:

```
def death(self):
    del self
```

Chamando no código:

```
if hunter_pos == target_pos and hunter_id != target_id:
    blob.death()
```

Sendo  **hunter_pos** a posição do "caçador", e **hunter_id** o número de identificação do "caçador", o mesmo valendo para o **target**, ou "alvo".

Porém esse método não funcionou comigo, até o momento foi o unico método de matar objetos que tentei, então qualquer outra sujestão está valendo.

Obs:"não funcionou", no sentido que o objeto não foi deletado/morto, ou seja o blob continua aparecendo na tela.

Código :

```
import pygame
import random
import time
from blob import Blob

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Blob World')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_environment(blob_list):
    game_display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for blob_dict in blob_list:
        for blob_id in blob_dict:
            blob = blob_dict[blob_id]
            hunter_pos = blob.position()
            hunter_id = blob_id
            for blob_id in blob_dict:
                blob = blob_dict[blob_id]
                target_pos = blob.position()
                target_id = blob_id
                if hunter_pos == target_pos and hunter_id != target_id:
                    blob.death()
                pygame.draw.circle(game_display, blob.color, [blob.x, blob.y], blob.size)
                blob.move()
                blob.check_boundaries()
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    blue_blobs = dict(enumerate([Blob((0, 0, 255), 800, 600, 8, 4, 5, -5) for i in range(6)]))
    red_blobs = dict(enumerate([Blob((255, 0, 0), 800, 600, 8, 4, 5, -5) for i in range(5)]))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        draw_environment([blue_blobs, red_blobs])
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Classe dos blobs:

```
import random

class Blob:
def __init__(self, color, x_boundary, y_boundary, size_max, size_min, mov_max, mov_min):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, x_boundary)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, y_boundary)
        self.size = random.randrange(size_min, size_max)
        self.color = color
        self.x_boundary = x_boundary
        self.y_boundary = y_boundary
        self.mov_min = mov_min
        self.mov_max = mov_max

    def move(self):
        self.x += random.randrange(self.mov_min, self.mov_max)
        self.y += random.randrange(self.mov_min, self.mov_max)

    def check_boundaries(self):
        if self.x < 0: self.x = 0
        elif self.x > self.x_boundary: self.x = self.x_boundary

        if self.y < 0: self.y = 0
        elif self.y > self.y_boundary: self.y = self.y_boundary

    def position(self):
        position_total =  self.x, self.y
        return position_total

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def death(self):
        del self
```

Comment: Como assim "não funcionou"? Além disso, coloque um [mcve] para a gente, porque não dá pra entender o que está acontecendo sem contexto.

Comment: Coloque seu código completo, por favor. Como está definido o objeto `blob`? Não seria algo como `target.death()` nesse caso?

Comment: Você está confundindo `del` com o `delete` do C++ (destruidor de objetos).